# Use nested subquery to fetch value with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named test_plan (id, unit, num)
I inserted some values

```
INSERT INTO `test_plan` (`id`, `unit`, `num`) VALUES 
('1', '1', '12'),
('2', '1', '13'),
('3', '1', '14'),
('4', '1', '10'),
('5', '2', '10'),
('6', '2', '9'),
('7', '2', '-1'),
('8', '2', '-1'),
('9', '2', '-1'),
('10', '3', '-1'),
('11', '3', '-1'),
('12', '3', '-1');
```

I have to fetch unit what is fraction of each unit to total unit when **num** is not equals to -1
i.e.after run the query it display as unit 1 is 100% completed, unit 2 is 40% completed, unit 3 is 0% completed as row wise. I can **count** the number of each **unit** but not the how much it completed.

I tried **JOIN** for this

```
SELECT a.unit, numb / count(*) as frac FROM test_plan as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT unit, count(num) as numb FROM test_plan where num != -1 group by unit) as b 
ON a.unit = b.unit group by a.unit;
```

Comment: What did you tried? What is the **specific** problem with your query? Showing some effort and writing good questions are highly improves your chance to get good answers. Please read [ask] in [help] to know more about the guidelines of asking in StackOverflow.

Comment: Essentially, you appear to want the SUM of one thing divided by the COUNT of another thing. Note that numbers do not normally need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select unit, 
    (sum(case when num = -1 then 0 else 1 end) / count(*)) * 100 as pct_complete
from lecture_plan group by unit;
```

there's no need for a nested sub query, the combination of aggregation and the case statement is sufficient

Comment: you've got to show someone a fish before you can teach them how to fish